# "import internal error" when scraping data

Tags: html, web-scraping, google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to insert a cell into a Google spreadsheet to see if a website contains Google AdSense. I've found that sites containing AdSense have the following HTML within the page:

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-1997390416756996" data-ad-slot="2796131549"></ins>
```

So I have the following function in my spreadsheet:

```
=importxml(A2,"//ins[@class='adsbygoogle']")
```

This returns #N/A, with an associated error of "Import Internal Error". I have found one entry on the site here for another XPath query at [recommendationXPath seems valid but Google spreadsheet just gives "import internal error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23237107/recommendationxpath-seems-valid-but-google-spreadsheet-just-gives-import-intern), which suggests that there is a Google error. Being a non-coder, I wondered whether this is the case here, or whether I've just written a nonsensical query..

Comment: See [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163)